# Chrome installer error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, installation

I installed a fresh installation of XP SP3 on a hyper-v virtual machine. Nothing is installed besides Microsoft Security essentials.

If I try to install chrome with the [alternate all users installer](http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=126299), I get this error:

`Google update installation failed with error 0x80070057`

I've tried a manual uninstall for chrome, cleaning the registry with ccleaner, running the installer as administrator, and starting from scratch by installing XP SP3 again.

Any ideas? I didn't encounter this issue a few months ago. Is there an older version of the alternative installer still available?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but take a look at [this thread](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?rlz=1C1GPCK_enIN398IN398&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Asocial.answers.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fen-US%2Fvistawu%2Fthread%2Fa9a2c92d-793b-4050-bdb1-720bb97bd78d%2F%3Fprof%3Drequired).

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt it's as simple as a permissions issue. I've tried installing as user with local admin privileged as well as the administrator user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sidestep the error by using the MSI installer.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a permissions problem, I would take a look at it with something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) setting a filter for chrome, and when you get the error, see exactly what operation failed.

Then, if it is something like a specific access denied, or file not found, or something similar, you can do more specific troubleshooting/repairs.

Comment: There were a number of "name not found" statuses, but nothing with a failed or denied status.